# The Java volatile Read Visibility Guarantee

Tags: multithreading, jvm, shared-memory, volatile, happens-before

I came across the following excerpt while reading on visibility guarantees provided by the JVM when reading volatile variables :
*"When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of ALL variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B AFTER reading the volatile variable."*

I have a question around this guarantee of JVM. Consider the below set of classes :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        POJO p = new POJO();
        new Th1(p).start();
        new Th2(p).start();
    }
}   
    public class Th1 extends Thread {
        private POJO p1 = null;
        public Th1(POJO obj) {
            p1 = obj;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            p1.a = 10; // t = 1
            p1.b = 10; // t = 2
            p1.c = 10; // t = 5;
            System.out.println("p1.b val: " + p1.b); // t = 8
            System.out.println("Thread Th1 finished"); // t = 9
        }
    }
    
    public class Th2 extends Thread {
        private POJO p2 = null;
        public Th2(POJO obj) {
            p2 = obj;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            p2.a = 30; // t = 3
            p2.b = 30; // t = 4
            int x = p2.c; // t = 6
            System.out.println("p2.b value: " + p2.b); // t = 7
        }
    }
    
    public class POJO {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        volatile int c = 1;
    }
```

Imagine the 2 threads Th1 and Th2 run in separate CPUs and the order in which their instructions execute is indicated by the comment in each line (in their run methods). The question I have is that :
When code "int x = p2.c;" executes at t = 6, variables visible to thread Th2 should be refreshed from main memory as per the above para. The main memory then as I understand would have all the writes from Th1 at this point. What value will the variable p2.b show then when it is printed at t = 7?

- Will p2.b show value of 10 as its value was refreshed from the read of the volatile variable p2.c?
- Or it will retain the value 30 somehow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no happens before edge between the write of `a` and the read of `a`. Since they are conflicting actions (at least one of them is a write) and are on the same address, there is a data-race and as a consequence, program behavior is undefined.

I think the following example explains the behavior of what you are looking for better:

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            POJO p = new POJO();
            new Th1(p).start();
            new Th2(p).start();
        }
    }   
    
    public class Th1 extends Thread {
        private POJO p1 = null;
        public Th1(POJO obj) {
            p1 = obj;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            a=1;
            b=1;
        }
    }
    
    public class Th2 extends Thread {
        private POJO p2 = null;
        public Th2(POJO obj) {
            p2 = obj;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(p.b==1)println("a must be 1, a="+p2.a);
        }
    }
    
    public class POJO {
        int a = 0;
        volatile int b = 0;
    }
```

There is a happens before edge between the write of `a` and the write of `b` (program order rule)
There is a happens before edge between the write of `b` and a subsequent read of `b` (volatile variable rule)
There is a happens before edge between the read of `b` and the read of `a` (program order rule)

Since the happens before relation is transitive, there is a happens before edge between the write of `a` and the read of `a`. So the second thread should see the `a=1` from the first thread.

Comment: Please write compilable code and verify the output before posting the code. The conditional check in Th2 is dependent on write in Th1 and since both threads are running concurrently, it could come out as true or false.

Comment: Apparently you are failing to understand how this works. A happens before edge between the write and the read is being build and this answers the question of the OP. I'm sure the OP is able to fix the compile error.

Comment: A happens-before edge only exists when the write `b=1;` has been executed before the `p.b==1` test. This is subject to an unknown execution timing and thread scheduling behavior. The example is correct in that the second thread will never print something different than `a must be 1, a=1`, however, in some executions, it might just print nothing. A better example would be `while(p.b != 1) {} println("a must be 1, a="+p2.a);` which is truly guaranteed to print a=1 on all systems with preemptive multitasking.

Comment: Sure; the example can be improved. But in both cases; if the thread sees the volatile write, it must see all changes before the volatile write. That was the intent of the example.

Answer (score 0):

For your code, p2.b is not guaranteed to be 10 or 30. The write is a race condition.

*"When thread A writes to a volatile variable and **subsequently** thread B reads that same variable, the values of ALL variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B AFTER reading the volatile variable."*

Your Th2 read of p2.c is not guaranteed to be done after the write of p1.c in Th1.

For the specific order you discussed, the read of p2.c in Th2 will **not** revert the value of p2.b to 10.

Comment: Since conflicting access is possible to the same variable that isn't ordered by a happens before edge, I would call this a data-race.

Comment: @pveentjer Does that mean even if the execution of the lines happens as described, the value of the variable b would still be unclear, when it is printed at t=7 ?

Comment: I would not try to reason about the value that can be seen in the presence of a data race; generally the behavior of a program is considered to be undefined. I have posted a full example that shows the intent of the quote you posted.